# Systemd - Unknown lvalue 'ConditionEnvironment' in section 'Unit'

Tags: linux, unix, environment-variables, systemd

Simple systemd service not working as expected

Service name: `test.service`

```
[Unit]
Description=Test
ConditionEnvironment=STACK=prod

[Service]
Restart=always
ExecStart=/bin/bash -l -c 'echo "do prod stuff!!!"'

[Install]
WantedBy=default.target
```

```
sudo systemctl daemon-reload
sudo service test restart
journalctl -u test -f
```

Systemd is giving an error when I try to use the `ConditionEnvironment` setting.

```
Apr 27 13:16:33 ip-172-31-105-2 systemd[1]: Failed to start Test.
Apr 27 13:19:53 ip-172-31-105-2 systemd[1]: /etc/systemd/system/test.service:3: Unknown lvalue 'ConditionEnvironment' in section 'Unit'
```

[Systemd ConditionEnvironment docs](https://www.freedesktop.org/software/systemd/man/systemd.unit.html#ConditionEnvironment=)

Answer (score 1):

While writing this question I found the answer.

The `ConditionEnvironment` setting was added in systemd version 246.

See release notes [here](https://lwn.net/Articles/827675/)

Seems Ubuntu is shipping with earlier versions.

```
ubuntu ~$ systemctl --version
systemd 237 (245.4-4ubuntu3.6)
```

Notes on updating systemd here: https://askubuntu.com/questions/627174/how-would-i-upgrade-systemd